# What is the menuInflater in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've been studying Kotlin and Android development, and studying the code samples in Android Studio, I've encountered this block:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }
```

I know that first you have to instantiate a variable for the inflater to use the `inflate()` method, but there is no `menuInflater` variable in this code. Looking at it, I see that it is similar to `getMenuInflater()` but I don't get how this is possible. I looked at the documentation and I have not found any explanation. Is `menuInflater` a variable, class, method?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: This method will genarate toolbar menu....   Check the offical doc. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#kotlin.    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu)
    return true
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

menuInflater is an object you can take from activity since activity and Menu class which you take menuInflater
shares common classes in the inheritance hierarchy. You can get the menuInflater object in activity, and it gives you chance
to get a menu file to your activity and use it there, Inflaters are mostly used to get some layouts and use it in another
layout e.g LayoutInflater, MenuInflater

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`MenuInflater` is class, You can find detailed Documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#kotlin)

- Also you can find a simple example for `MenuInflater` [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/popup-menu-in-android-with-example/)

Answer (score 0):

It's Kotlin's syntactic sugar. `getXxx()` Java method can be invoked as if it was a Kotlin `xxx` property.

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters